# Order of ultradistribution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions

I know that the order of any distribution of compact support is finite. Is this true in the case of ultra distribution of compact support ( dual of Denjoy-Carleman space)?

Comment: If an ultradistribution is of finite order, then it is automatically a distribution.

Comment: Thank you. I see it now.